# parameter Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm trying to make calls to RESTful API of Amazon but it seems it was a bad starting or something!

I've got this message:

```
<ItemLookupErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-08-01/">
<Error>
<Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
<Message>
Value 2015-3-24T18:38:26Z for parameter Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format.
</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>77d4ca11-4f95-42d2-b85a-a4042abded80</RequestId>
</ItemLookupErrorResponse>
```

This is the code in JavaScript:

```
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth()+1;
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var hours = today.getHours() < 10 ? "0"+today.getHours() : today.getHours(); 
    var seconds = today.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0"+today.getSeconds() : today.getSeconds();
    var mins = today.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0"+today.getMinutes() : today.getMinutes();
    var time = encodeURIComponent(year+"-"+month+"-"+day+"T"+hours+":"+mins+":"+seconds+"Z");
    var messageToEncrypt ="GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n\
        /onca/xml\nAWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSID&ItemId=0679722769&&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp="+time+"&Version=2013-08-01";

    var sig = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(messageToEncrypt, "SECRET KEY");

    var request = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=AccessID&Operation=ItemLookup&ItemId=0976925524&ResponseGroup=SalesRank&Version=2013-08-01&Timestamp="+time+"&Signature="+sig;


    function GET(url) {
        var oFrame = document.getElementById("MyAjaxFrame");
        if (!oFrame) {
            oFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
            oFrame.style.display = "none";
            oFrame.id = "MyAjaxFrame";
            document.body.appendChild(oFrame);
        }
        oFrame.src = url;
    }

    GET(request);
```

Is there something wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: It needs to be `03` for the month. But WTH don't you simply use [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)???

Comment: The message seems pretty clear to me. Your timestamp is not a valid ISO8601 string

Comment: @Bergi Yes that solved the problem, now I've something wrong in the signature. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably missing the leading zero in months and days. Your value should be probably `2015-03-24T18:38:26Z`

Like @Bergi suggested in comment - use [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

Comment: Thats solved the problem:
`var today = new Date();
time = today.toISOString();
time = encodeURIComponent(time);`
Thanks.